# Remote Debug dotnet test: vstest.console.pdb not loaded

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, remote-debugging, pdb-files, dotnet-test

I have a C# application, and in addition, an NUnit testing project which is being compiled to a dll.

I used to copy it to a remote platform, there I run it using this command:

```
dotnet test MyTests.dll
```

And the tests are running.

Now I want to debug a test, so I opened VS2017 Remote Debugger on the remote platform, and Attached to Process in Visual Studio of the development platform.

In the remote I see:

```
Waiting for debugger attach...
Process Id: 6116, Name: dotnet
```

But in Visual Studio I get:

[image: vstest.console.pdb not loaded]

How can I solve this? Where can i find this pdb?

=====================================================

NOTE 1: I copy the whole compilation folder to the remote, including PDBs of course.

NOTE 2: I set `$env:VSTEST_HOST_DEBUG=1` in Powershell.

Comment: PDB's should be on `Microsoft Symbol Servers`. Can you share the package version of `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`?

Comment: Also you don't need to debug vstest.console, add a function breakpoint with the name of your test function and hit F5. It should hit your code.